# Is there any way to connect to google cloud project without using Client Library?

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, client-library

Can we connect to google cloud project, without using Client Library?

What is `BigQuery API`? Is it similar to `bq-command line-tool`?

If not, is there any way to convert `bq-commandline-tool` to  API for usage in Python?

Comment: Did you try a Google search? There is a [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/), which the client libraries and the command line client all use. I feel like your question is too broad; it doesn't seem like you have a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly recommended to use the Google Cloud client libraries when available, but if you wish to call a Google Cloud Platform REST API from Python without a client library you can use an HTTP library such as [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

One thing client libraries handle for you is [authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/). To authenticate to a Google API with Python, I highly recommend the [google-auth Python library](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Without an authentication library, you would have to implement the OAuth2 spec yourself, which is discouraged.